# issue with Threadsafe singleton with semaphore

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

I have written a simple singleton application.

The following is my sample main class

```
// ThreadsafeSingletonUsingSemaphore.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "MySingleton.h"
using namespace std;

int i =0;
#define THREADCOUNT 100
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lParam);
HANDLE g_semaphore = NULL;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    g_semaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL,1,1,_T("TreadOne"));
    HANDLE hThread[THREADCOUNT];
    DWORD aThreadID;

    for(int iCount = 0; iCount < THREADCOUNT ; iCount++)
    {
        hThread[iCount] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, 0,0, &aThreadID);
        if( hThread[iCount] == NULL )
        {
            cout<<"CreateThread error: %d" << GetLastError() << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(THREADCOUNT, hThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

    // Close thread and semaphore handles
    for(int i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ )
        CloseHandle(hThread[i]);

    cout << MySingleton::getInstance().getCounter() << endl ;

    CloseHandle(g_semaphore);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    //DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(g_semaphore,INFINITE);
    //if(WAIT_OBJECT_0 == result)
        MySingleton::getInstance().incrementCouner();
    //ReleaseSemaphore(g_semaphore,1, NULL);
    return TRUE;
}
```

This is my singleton implementation class.

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "MySingleton.h"

MySingleton* MySingleton::m_instance = NULL;
HANDLE MySingleton::m_hSem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, _T("MySingleton"));
HANDLE MySingleton::m_One = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, _T("MyOne"));

MySingleton::MySingleton(void) : m_counter(0)
{
}

MySingleton::~MySingleton(void)
{
    cout << "destructor" << endl;
    CloseHandle(m_hSem);
    CloseHandle(m_One);
}

MySingleton& MySingleton::getInstance()
{
    DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(m_hSem, INFINITE);

    if(WAIT_OBJECT_0 == result)
    {
        if(m_instance == NULL)
        {
            cout << "creating" << endl;
            m_instance = new MySingleton();
        }
    }
    ReleaseSemaphore(m_hSem,1,NULL);
    return *m_instance;
}

void MySingleton::setCouner(int iCount_in)
{
    m_counter = iCount_in;
}
int MySingleton::getCounter()
{
    return m_counter;
}

void MySingleton::incrementCouner() 
{ 
    DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(m_One, INFINITE);
    if(WAIT_OBJECT_0 == result)
        m_counter++;
    ReleaseSemaphore(m_One,1,NULL);
}
```

This is my .h class.

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class MySingleton
{
private:
    static HANDLE m_hSem, m_One;
    HANDLE m_hCountSem;
    static MySingleton* m_instance;
    int m_counter;
    MySingleton();
    MySingleton(const MySingleton& obj_in);
    MySingleton& operator=(const MySingleton& obj_in);
public:
    ~MySingleton(void);

    static MySingleton& getInstance();
    void setCouner(int iCount_in);
    int getCounter();

    void incrementCouner();
};
```

The problem is the final value of counter is never 100. can someone please explain me why and what is that i am doing wrong.I am not able to understand the problem. When I introduce sleep in the main before creating each thread, it works fine.

Comment: Why not use C++'s own threading features, rather than Win32?

Comment: @prv do not edit questions with answers.  Post corrected code in an answer, not on the question.  If someone solves your problem upvote and give them a checkmark, and if they help upvote.  Self answering is permitted; editing questions to make existing answers make no sense is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that call to `WaitForMultipleObjects` handles up to `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` which, at least in Visual Studio 2017, is 64.

Notice how your call to `WaitForMultipleObjects` to join threads returns `WAIT_FAILED`.

In order to wait for more objects one should, [according to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx):

> To wait on more than MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, use one of the following methods:
>
> - Create a thread to wait on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, then wait on that thread plus the other handles. Use this technique to break the handles into groups of MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS.
> - Call RegisterWaitForSingleObject to wait on each handle. A wait thread from the thread pool waits on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS registered objects and assigns a worker thread after the object is signaled or the time-out interval expires.

Comment: you are totally correct. Thanks a lot Now I got what is the issue. Thanks a lot once again

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write all of that code. The easiest way to implement a threadsafe singleton is to use Scott Meyer's singleton idiom:

```
class Singleton {
    int counter;
    mutable std::mutex counter_guard;
    Singleton() {}
public:
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete;

    static Singleton& instance() {
        static Singleton theInstance;
        return theInstance;
    }

    void setCounter(int newVal) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(counter_guard);
        counter = newVal;
    }  
    void incrementCounter() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(counter_guard);
        ++counter;
    }  
    int getCounter() const {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(counter_guard);
        return counter;
    }  
};
```

---

An even easier way would be to use a [`std::atomic<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) type for the `counter` member variable. Then the mutex and lock guards can be omitted at all.

Comment: I believe writing the singleton is the part of this excercise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is not with the single ton. The problem is with the counter that i have in singleton. I was expecting at the end of program execution, the counter value will be same as my thread count in main but it is not. Which is what i am not able to understand.

Comment: @PrV Well, I was more going to answer what you had put in your question title. Anyways, the code I show is the idiomatic way to implement a (thread safe) Singleton in C++.

Comment: Sorry, I am just learning. I know my code could be idiotic. I really don't understand this thread safe thing. So sorry once again.

Comment: @user0042 Well, the OP's singleton does actually contain some data, which yours does not. Yours is thread-safe with regard to singleton creation, but would not be if the thing contained any data which needed to be accessed post creation, which every singleton I've ever seen needs to do.

Comment: @Neil That can be easily added with some mutex protection.